# Getting JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

Is there any way that I can print/NSLOG the string or the array that is being returned by the API in this following login code of mine:

```
-(void)loginToAPI:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password {

    NSString *controller = @"login";
    NSString *action =  @"authenticate";

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"username": email,
                             @"userpass": password,
                             @"controller":  controller,
                             @"action": action,
                             @"app_id": APP_ID,
                             @"app_key": APP_KEY};
    NSLog(@"params %@", params);

    if ([self isNetworkAvailable]) {
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *client = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        client.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [client.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
        [client POST:[[Config sharedInstance] getAPIURL]
          parameters:params
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSDictionary *jsonObject= responseObject;
                 NSString *status = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"status"];
                 NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", jsonObject);
                 if ([status isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
                     NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                     NSDictionary *data = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"data"];
                     NSDictionary *userDict = [data objectForKey:@"user"];
                     NSDictionary *djsaDict = [data objectForKey:@"djsa"];

                     User *currentUser = [[User alloc] initWithProperties:userDict];

                     [currentUser save];

                     DJSA_Cutomer *djsa = [[DJSA_Cutomer alloc] initWithProperties:djsaDict];


                     NSData *userData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:currentUser];
                     NSData *djsaData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:djsa];

                     [userDefaults setObject:userData forKey:@"currentUser"];
                     [userDefaults setObject:djsaData forKey:@"djsa_customer"];
                     [userDefaults synchronize];

                     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"LOGIN_SUCCESS" object:currentUser userInfo:nil];

                 } else {
                     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"LOGIN_FAILED" object:nil userInfo:nil];
                 }
             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error - loginToAPI: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"SERVER_ERROR" object:nil userInfo:nil];
             }];
    }
}
```

It is always failing and going to the part "Request Failed with Error - loginToAPI". Is it possible to see the actual values returned by the server so I can diagnose the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the full log of `"Request Failed with Error - loginToAPI"`? You can hide your url if needed. If I remember correctly AFNetworking encapsulated the errors (and the data) inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution to it in my case was

```
client.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

I did that but I was still getting same error. The problem was that I was setting client.requestSerializer  instead of client.responseSerializer. Small mistakes but takes lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the status code off the response property from the operation object which should give you some idea of what went wrong:

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error - loginToAPI: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSHTTPURLResponse localized​String​For​Status​Code:operation.response.statusCode]);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"SERVER_ERROR" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}];
```

Otherwise, it's best to use a tool like [Charles web proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/download/latest-release/) to inspect the actual request and response. It has a free trial which should be sufficient to do what you need, and is relatively easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
client.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [client.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

with this:

```
[client.securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
[client.securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
client.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```